# Fix jerky motion of the user icon when clicking on search field

Tags: feature-request, search, top-bar

Would it be possible to fix the jerky motion of the user icon and reputation that occurs when you click on the search field when the viewport is a certain width?

View the following gif to see what I am talking about. Notice how the reputation count moves slightly to the left when you click the search field. And then when you collapse it, the reputation count moves to the right and then moves left. I think the reputation count should stay in a fixed position and the search box should expand to the left. This only happens when the window width is very small. I sometimes have it snapped to one side of my screen. Is it possible to fix whatever is causing this?

[image: Top Bar jerky motion]

Comment: I can only reproduce this when the window width is really small - such that the sidebar is near invisible.

Comment: @Oded Yes me too. But I sometimes have the browser snapped to one side of my screen with something else in the other half. It is still somewhat visually distracting.

Comment: @Oded I can reproduce this with windows up to 807 pixels. Given that 800px is my preferred window width at home, I wouldn't call this “really small”. It's half the width of my monitor.

Comment: #SmallMonitorProblems

Answer (score 3):

Given my low hopes of this being fixed, here's my custom CSS which condenses the top bar and moves the search box towards the left, making it expand seamlessly towards the right. If you don't like all these changes, pick and choose. I did this primarily [because I can't stand the animation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343949), and removing the animation would solve your problem too.

Screenshot (combined with [Make the indicator of unread inbox messages more visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343830/make-the-indicator-of-unread-inbox-messages-more-visible/343948#343948)):
[image: screenshot]

I use Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stylish/), [IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/305105/equivalent-to-stylish-plug-in-for-ie-9); [quickstart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251473/new-beta-style-is-much-harder-on-my-eyes-looking-for-css-overrides-to-fix), [detailed explanations](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964)). I'm still experimenting, so this might still change. Firefox syntax:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("meta.stackoverflow.com") {

/* Less space around the logo */
div.-main a.-logo {
    padding-left: 4px !important;
    padding-right: 4px !important;
}

/* Shorten “Documentation” to "Docum" */
a#nav-docs {
    width: 4em !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}

/* Move the search bar left of the navigation buttons */
div.-main nav.navigation {
    order: 2;
}
div.-main form.searchbar {
    order: 1;
}

/* Turn off the animation when (un)focusing the search box (and everywhere else) */
* {
    transition: none !important;
/*    animation-duration: 0s !important;*/
}

/* Shrink the left margin of the search bar */
form.searchbar {
    padding-left: 4px !important;
}
form.searchbar input {
    padding-left: 4px !important;
    color: black !important; /*better contrast than the default grey*/
}

/* Hide the search icon? That affects the submit button as well. */
form.searchbar svg {
    /*display: none !important;*/
}

/* Hide the useless, very wide reputation and badge display */
a.my-profile div.-rep {
    display:none !important;
}
a.my-profile div.-badges {
    display:none !important;
}
}
```

For Chrome, omit the first two lines and the trailing closing brace.

Thanks to Keen and Mad Scientist for the help with CSS.

Known issues:

- The search icon overlaps the placeholder text when the box is empty.
- This doesn't keep the bar expanded when the window loses focus.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I also don't like the animation in general.