# What is the reasoning behind the Stack Overflow search box animating and increasing in size?

Tags: discussion, design, search, user-experience

I really think Meta Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow's search bar doesn't need to change size. Most searches don't involve the size of that textbox (it is too large).

I like what SE has done on all the other sites. Maintain the size and simply bring forth a magnifying glass icon button that appears and change the textbox color from a light shade of gray to white.

Why don't / can't we do that on SO and Meta.SO? I also think it's odd to shift the search from the right side to the left as we read from left to right. If anything, I would of shifted the search box from left to right...But again I don't recommend doing any of that.

I would maintain the size of the search box and not animate anything. The textbox animating and actually hiding the other links is rather strange.

Comment: It animates? Never noticed. No one uses search anyway.

Comment: Because the size of it is different for different people based on what is currently in the header. For example, not all users have access to the review queues. Not all users get the smaller SO logo, etc. For those who have the most in the header, the search box is rather small. Even moreso when the 'New Feature!' announcement appears.

Comment: Agree with OP here. Don't move my caret like that while I'm looking at it please. :) I don't buy the argument about users without access to review queues etc, it behaves the same in an incognito non-authenticated tab. It actually removes most of the menu meaning it takes a blur event to get it back.

Comment: On all other sites the topbar isn't cluttered with Questions, Developer Jobs, Tags and Users *menu* items. Other sites have a subheader for those links which is lacking on SO. In the initial roll-out the feedback was that the searchbox was too small. So now we have this animating/growing box that matches, when expanded, with the layout of other sites. You can't make everyone happy I guess.

Comment: I put it down to junk food:)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the UI designers and their decisions, but I think that it's because the topbar menu points (the other navigation like questions, tags, users) are in the same bar as the search on SO.

On other SE sites with the new topbar, the navigation links are on a seperate bar underneath, so it's smaller on SO I suppose.

I suppose they got complaints that the searchbar is too small for some users (like high reputation users) and did this to address that concern.

Comment: *"On other SE sites with the new topbar, the search is its own seperate bar..."* Uhh, not on my screen?

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins looking at it again, that was an imprecise statement of me. The other clutter "questions, tags, users" is on a different bar on the other sites

Comment: Ah, I thought that might be what you meant. The "navigation links", I suppose you'd call it, rather than "clutter". :-)

Comment: @CodyS.Pumpkins fair enough

Answer (score 1):

The problem of UX design is that you have to take into account edge cases. Old school was that you had a large text box eating up a decent chunk of real estate, or you had a box crammed in somewhere that wasn't big enough.

The new "cool kid CSS" thing is to minimize the search box and then stretch it in over other elements. While this is sometimes too minimalist ([Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/) opted for no box at all, just a search icon, which makes it unintuitive to find), I think the SO approach is a "just right" option. Keeps the search box (obvious to users where to search) but tries to provide enough room for larger searches (if you're searching you don't need the navigation links).

Comment: I could *maybe* get behind this if it didn't zoom away in the *opposite* direction of the text that I'm trying to focus on. (Maybe not even then, but it would be a lot less obnoxious.)

Comment: Well, maybe drop the animation (which [seems to be the real complaint here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343822/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-3)). Ars just opts to have it "pop in" and that might be a better UX anyways