# Make the indicator of unread inbox messages more visible

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, global-inbox

Inbox indicator in the old top bar: [image: inbox indicator in the old top bar]

Inbox indicator in the [new top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update): [image: inbox indicator in the new top bar]

That number has gotten a lot smaller.¹

I admit that it makes sense to still show the icon, so as to give an indication of what that number is about². But the number is now so small that it's barely readable. And it's become a lot less visible that the number is present at all. A 21x13 red rectangle is more visible than a 14x10 rectangle. It doesn't help that red-on-white is slightly less contrasted than red-on-black³.

Please make the inbox indicator more visible (so that the yes/no state is more obvious), at least by making it bigger (so that the number is easier to read).

¹  <sub>Oh, you know what I mean.</sub> 
²  <sub>It would be more useful if the [icon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662122_207461) was recognizable, but that's a separate matter.</sub> 
³  <sub>Not that I mind the white background; that too is a separate matter, and the color difference wouldn't help much anyway.</sub>

Comment: You don't like that the icon for the inbox is an inbox?  Discussions over icons always have a way of making one feel old...

Comment: @Servy I didn't know it was supposed to be an inbox tray until someone told me, and even after being told I don't *see* an inbox tray when I look at it. Regarding the title, good idea, done.

Comment: @Gilles I mean, this icon is hardly a unique way of [representing an inbox](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=inbox+icon&espv=2&biw=1680&bih=960&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjot9vc1pDSAhWGgLwKHZhcBHoQ_AUIBigB).

Comment: Yes, please.  I actually pay attention to what the number *is*; it's not just a toggle for me.  Sometimes I know what some of the messages are and am deliberately *not* opening yet, but I want to know if the number goes up.  I can't do that now without moving to right in front of the monitor and squinting.

Comment: IIRC it was blue when it was first released to power users, then users complained that it drew _too much_ attention to the number and was distracting, so it was changed back to the original red. Now you're saying that it doesn't draw enough attention.

Comment: @TinyGiant The complaints that I saw for the blue was because all of the different notifications looked so similar, you'd end up mistaking new review actions or rep changes as a new inbox notification.  It wasn't that the inbox notification stood out too much.  Making the inbox notifications stand out more makes it harder to mistake other types of notifications (that won't be as prominent) for it.

Comment: @TinyGiant “[The lack of color differentiation is a bug that will be fixed before launch.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week#comment444340_343216)” I haven't seen any complaint that the *inbox* number drew too much attention; there's a complaint in that same comment thread that the *review* number drew too much attention.

Comment: Ahh, I must have misremembered that. I didn't pay much attention to it because it all seemed silly to me.

Answer (score 2):

Given my low hopes of this being fixed, here's my custom CSS. Here's how the right-hand side of my top bar looks now:

[image: top bar right-hand side screenshot]

I use Stylish ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stylish/), [IE?](https://superuser.com/questions/305105/equivalent-to-stylish-plug-in-for-ie-9); [quickstart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251473/new-beta-style-is-much-harder-on-my-eyes-looking-for-css-overrides-to-fix), [detailed explanations](https://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964)). I'm still experimenting, so this might still change. Firefox syntax:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com"), domain("meta.stackoverflow.com") {

/* More visible inbox indicator */
span.indicator-badge._important {
    font-size: 16px !important;
    /*font-weight: bold !important;*/
    top: 12px !important;
    left: 5px !important;
    right: 5px !important;
}

/* Hide the annoying "achievements" indicator */
a.js-achievements-button {
    display:none !important;
}

/* Stop the review indicator from moving when the cursor approaches */
span.indicator-badge._reviews {
    top: 12px !important;
}
}
```

For Chrome, omit the first two lines and the trailing closing brace.

Thanks to Keen and Mad Scientist for the help with CSS.